# (Reverse) Traverse XPath Query for Accessing a DIV with a particular Text Value

Tags: html, xpath

Working with a `DOM` that has the same HTML loop 100+ times that looks like this

```
<div class="intro"> 
  <div class="header"> 
     <h1 class="product-code"> <span class="code">ZY001</span> <span class="intro">ZY001 Title/Intro</span> </h1> 
  </div> 
<div> 
<table> 
<tbody>
   <tr> 
        <td>Available</td>
        <td> S </td>
        <td> M </td>
        <td> XL </td>
  </tr>
```

I was previously using this XPath Query to get ALL the node values back (all 100+ instances of the DOM Query in connection with the variable nodes that may contain in `Available`

```
//div[@class='intro']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Available')]/following-sibling::td
```

> object(DOMNodeList)[595]
>     public 'length' => int 591

Now I am needing to target the `product-code` / `code` specifically to retrieve all the `td` attributes for a particular `code`

Because the div that contains the unique identifier (in the example above, `ZY001`) is not a direct ancestor, my thinking is I have to do a Reverse XPath Query

Here's one of my attempts:

```
//h1[@class='product-code']/span[contains(@class, 'code') and text() = 'ZY001']/../../div[@class='intro']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Available')]/following-sibling::td
```

As I am defining `/span[contains(@class, 'code') and text() = 'ZY001']` and then attempting to traverse the dom backwards twice using `/../../` I was hoping/expecting to get back the div[@class='intro'] with the text `ZY001` immediately above it, or rather a `public 'length' => int 1`

But all my attempts thus far have resulted in `0` results. Not `false`, indicating an improper XPath, but `0`.

How can I modify my XPath Query to get back the single instance in the one-of-many `<div class="intro">`'s that contain the `<h1 class="product-code">`/`<span class="code">` text value `ZY001`?

Comment: You want to get <td> elements under <div class="intro"> where code us ZY001 and 1st <td> is Available, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes correct. My difficulty is its not a direct descendent.

Comment: Ok. Take a look at my answer. Can explain more if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
//h1[@class='product-code']/span[contains(@class, 'code') and text() = 'ZY001']/../../../div/table/tbody
```

instead of

```
//h1[@class='product-code']/span[contains(@class, 'code') and text() = 'ZY001']/../../div[@class='intro']/div/table/tbody
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try as soon as I get home (at work right now and don't have access to the code)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was going for thank you very much!  More specifically `//h1[@class='product-code']/span[contains(@class, 'code') and text() = 'ZY001']/../../../div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Available')]/following-sibling::td`

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below xpath's for that:

```
//div[@class='intro' and //h1[@class='product-code']/span[@class='code' and text()='ZY001']]//tbody/tr[td[text()='Available']]/td[2]

//div[@class='intro' and //span[@class='code' and text()='ZY001']]//tbody/tr[td[text()='Available']]/td[2]

//div[@class='intro' and //span[@class='code' and text()='ZY001']]//tr[td[text()='Available']]/td[2]
```

Change `td[2]` to `td[3]` and `td[4]` to get the 3rd and 4th `td` respectively

Comment: Thanks for the variation of possibilities, they are interesting.  One thing to their detriment is they all seem to process much slower than @StevenLiang XPath Query.  They are different though and I'm going to do some more testing with them tomorrow and choose an answer.

Comment: I'm actually kind of curious about it, but the reason it seems to be going so slow is it it's getting all nodes (in 99% of iterations.. - still want to test it as I said to figure out what I'm doing.), meaning `td[2]` brings back 100 (which is every iteration of the loop), meaning the query is not exclusive to the unique identifier/`ZY001`).. Will look again tomorrow but my edit in the answer below yours is working as reference, aside from bringing back `NULL` instead of `Available` (if bringing back all `td`'s in the `nodeValue` as your does - which doesn't particularly matter, but reference.

Comment: Yes got me thinking as well, I've never looked at xpath like which would be faster, I used to look at it like what is most likely not to change. I am going to do some research as well. Thanks for mentioning this

Comment: It's breaking my mind too much man :P.. So yeah, the queries are ignoring the `text() = 'whatever'` for the `div` class `intro` encapsulation, or in other words `//div[@class='intro' and //h1[@class='product-code']/span[@class='code' and text()='ZY001']]//tbody/tr[td[text()='Available']]` brings back the exact same XPath results as this query `//div[@class='intro' and //h1[@class='product-code']/span]//tbody/tr[td[text()='Available']]`.  Why this is, I'm not sure.  It was an interesting strategy though and got me thinking in other directions with this.  As for the answer though, I'll

Comment: have to go with @StevenLiang's response, as it is working with the `text()` path bringing back the associated td's per.. and is working as needed for my application.  Thank you again for the attempt :)